# Использование Visual Studio

Tags: ide, visual-studio

Привет,  два вопроса по использованию Visial Studio.

1. По оформлению. Создаю тестовый класс, там фигурные скобки, нажимаю Enter, следующая строчка красиво ложится под предыдущию, отступая несолько пробелов внутрь. Такой каскад получается. А иногда такое не происходит. Нажимаю Enter и все фигурные скобки ({) ложатся друг под другом на одинаковом расстоянии от левого края. Почему?
2. Есть такая ситуация. Сверху код, снизу код. Между ними несколько раз нажали Enter, оба кода расположены на одинаковом расстоянии от левого края. Как сделать так, чтобы с помощью клавы выделить нижний код и перетащить его под верхний код на то же расстояние от левого края?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Почитайте про [IntelliSense](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hcw1s69b.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Установите [Visual Asist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) и будет вам чуть больше счастья, чем со встроенным IntelliSense.